# Given a Boolean function, decide if it can be implemented only with the $\mathrm{AND}$, $\mathrm{OR}$, and $\mathrm{NOT}$ gates

Tags: boolean-algebra

**True or false? Prove or justify, respectively. "Given $$f(x,y,z)=x\cdot z+\overline y\cdot\overline{z+\overline x}$$ can be implemented in a circuit formed only by an $\mathrm{AND}$ gate, an $\mathrm{OR}$ and a $\mathrm{NOT}$".**

---

I think it is false.

\begin{align*}
f(x,y,z)&=x\cdot z+\overline y\cdot\overline{z+\overline x}\\
&=x\cdot z+\overline y\cdot\overline z\cdot x\\
&=x\cdot z+\overline y\cdot\overline z\\
&=(x\cdot z)+(\overline y\cdot\overline z),
\end{align*}

so the minimum expression of $f$ has two $\mathrm{AND}$s, one $\mathrm{OR}$ and two $\mathrm{NOT}$s.

Even if we try to apply De Morgan's Law to the original expression of $f$ we end up with $$\overline{x+\overline z\cdot y+(z+\overline x)}\implies\overline{x+\overline x+\overline z\cdot y+z}\implies\overline{\mathrm T+\overline z\cdot y+z}\implies\overline{\mathrm T}\implies\mathrm C.$$ Is any of the "answers" correct? How would you do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is $x\cdot z+\bar y\cdot\bar z\cdot x=x\cdot z+\bar y\cdot\bar z$?

Comment: Isn't $f(x,y,z)=x\cdot(\bar y+z)$?

Comment: Note that $xz+\bar{y}\bar{z}x=x(z+\bar{y}\bar{z})=x(z+\bar{y})$, hence the answer is true.

Comment: @Galc127 thank you, super clear *engineering student* $\ddot\smile$! Does not the statement speak of a circuit? Why are you ignoring it?

Comment: @bof because I do not know how to correctly put parentheses to separate the terms.

Comment: @manooooh, the function can be implemented using one NOT gate, one OR gate and one AND gate, I didn't ignore it.

Comment: @Galc127 ok. Do you want to post an answer?